# What happens when server request files exceed memory size?

Tags: python, django, file, memory

I'm trying to figure out what happens when files of varying sizes are uploaded to the server at the same time and their collective size exceeds that of the memory.

More specifically, what does Django do then? Does virtual memory come into play or are the files moved to disk?

According to Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/uploads/#custom-upload-handlers]), you can specify the `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` value which decides whether the temp file remains in memory or goes to disk. **If I set this value to, say, 50 GB, and I send one or more files at the same time to the server, AND my RAM is only 16 GB, what happens then?**

I'm asking this question because I need to encrypt the files I receive at the server without saving them flat anywhere in the disk, even as a temporary file, due to sensitivity of the data. I want to make sure that under no circumstance the file(s) will be moved from the (volatile) memory to (secondary) disk storage in its original form.

Comment: That depends on your operating system as well

Comment: Okay, what will be the behavior on Windows 10 and Ubuntu?

Comment: Try it your self if possible.

Comment: I am working on it. But I was hoping to find an answer to save me time.